# Treat every "enter" as line break when that data comes out of a database

Tags: php, mysqli

So basicly I have information stored like this in the database:

```
13:41:24 - Lord_Nico_of_Vanguard has joined the game with ID: 108857

13:41:32 - Lord_Nico_of_Vanguard joined the Variance Trade & Mercenaries Company.

13:42:55 - *FACTION* Variance Trade & Mercenaries Company [Lord_Nico_of_Vanguard] bonjour mona mie

13:43:04 - *FACTION* Variance Trade & Mercenaries Company [Lord_Nico_of_Vanguard] much french

13:43:45 - *LOCAL* [Lord_Nico_of_Vanguard] sure

13:43:47 - Lord_Nico_of_Vanguard has equipped Morningstar

13:43:47 - Lord_Nico_of_Vanguard has picked up Morningstar

13:43:49 - *LOCAL* [Lord_Nico_of_Vanguard] thank you
```

This is also how I want to display it with a echo, but when I try to do that I get this output:

```
13:41:24 - Lord_Nico_of_Vanguard has joined the game with ID: 108857 13:41:32 - Lord_Nico_of_Vanguard joined the Variance Trade & Mercenaries Company. 13:42:55 - *FACTION* Variance Trade & Mercenaries Company [Lord_Nico_of_Vanguard] bonjour mona mie 13:43:04 - *FACTION* Variance Trade & Mercenaries Company [Lord_Nico_of_Vanguard] much french 13:43:45 - *LOCAL* [Lord_Nico_of_Vanguard] sure 13:43:47 - Lord_Nico_of_Vanguard has equipped Morningstar 13:43:47 - Lord_Nico_of_Vanguard has picked up Morningstar 13:43:49 - *LOCAL* [Lord_Nico_of_Vanguard] thank you
```

I am echoing my lines like this: `echo '<b>What happened:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><div id="what_happened" style="max-height:600px; overflow:auto;">' . $player_complaints_offence . '</div></b><p></fieldset><p>';`

Is there any way to replace the enter spaces with 
 or something with PHP preg replace? I tried to search for such but couldn't find anything.

Thank you for your time reading this.

Comment: Are you displaying the info in the browser? if so, have you wrapped pre-tags around it? (since browsers do not display linebreaks)

Comment: I am just echoing it like this: echo '<b>What happened:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><div id="what_happened" style="max-height:600px; overflow:auto;">' . $player_complaints_offence . '</div></b><p>            </fieldset><p>';

Comment: try this http://php.net/nl2br

Comment: add pre-tags: 
`echo '<b>What happened:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><div id="what_happened" style="max-height:600px; overflow:auto;"><pre>' . $player_complaints_offence . '</pre></div></b><p> </fieldset><p>';`

Comment: Please put it as an answer so I can accept it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pre-tags:

```
echo '<b>What happened:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>
        <div id="what_happened" style="max-height:600px; overflow:auto;">
            <pre>' . $player_complaints_offence . '</pre>
       </div>
    </b><p> </fieldset><p>';
```